# how to initialize a list of another class into a class constructor

Tags: list, vb.net, class, constructor

Let suppose there is a class called Feature

```
Public Class Feature
 Public Property featureName As String 
 Public Property sRanges As Short 
 Public Property eRange As Short  
End Class
```

Now there is another 2nd class called channel as below where I am declaring a list of type first class. Which I can initialize using constructor like

```
Public Class Channel
Public Property channelName As String
Public Property Features As List(Of Feature)    

  Public sub New()
    features =New List(Of Feature)() 
  End sub
End Class
```

Now I have another Third class where I am creating a list of type channel,

```
Public Class Fixture    
Public Property Address As Short
Public Property EndAddress As Short
Public Property FixtureName As String
Public Property Description As String
Public Property Channels As List(Of Channel)

Public Sub New()
    Channels = New List(Of Channel)()
End Sub
End Class
```

Now my question is when we use first class into 2nd class and 2nd class into 3d class as a list like in this example here, what is the best and correct way to initialize all these cascaded lists.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong to begin with. You don't need to do anything in the constructor. Build the list creation into the property, e.g.

```vb
Public Class Parent

    Public ReadOnly Property Children As New List(Of Child)

End Class
```

Note that the property is `ReadOnly`, which doesn't stop the existing `List` object being modified - that uses the getter, not the setter - but does prevent the property being set to a different `List` object. That's how it should pretty much always be done and is done throughout .NET.

You can do the same in the `Child` class as well, e.g.

```vb
Public Class Child

    Public ReadOnly Property Grandchildren As New List(Of Grandchild)

End Class
```

and that's all you need. That can happen through as many layers and as many branches as you like. Populating the lists is another matter - how you do that is up to you and may vary - but creating them is simple. It happens automatically when you create an instance.